# A way to see the number of active IAP subscribers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

Apologies if this question has an obvious answer, but dozens of Google and Stack Overflow searches haven't brought me any closer to the answer...

We have an iOS app that uses In-App Purchase to allow users to sign up for a subscription. This subscription automatically bills monthly.  In iTunes Connect I can see the total number of subscription *transactions* being processed each month, but I can't see how many subscribers we're adding / retaining.

Ideally, we'd like to be able to see:

- Total number of active subscribers
- Number of new subscribers in this period
- Number of cancellations in this period

Any ideas on how to find this info - either from iTunes Connect or a third-party solution - would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received an email today that you now have visibility to active subscriptions. Log into iTunes connect, Go to "Sales and Trends" then select "Subscriptions" from the report chooser.

[Report Chooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDCPv.png)

Comment: Can't find it unfortunately